# Python: Print using ascii codes

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii

I'm a beginner in python and I'm having a problem in this program:

Here's the NodeList first:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,initdata):
        self.data = initdata
        self.next = None

    def getData(self):
        return self.data

    def getNext(self):
        return self.next

    def setData(self,newdata):
        self.data = newdata

    def setNext(self,newnext):
        self.next = newnext
```

My problem is in this program: (The print)

```
from NodeList import Node

class StackLL:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def pushSLL(self,item):
        temp = Node(str(item))
        temp.setNext(self.head)
        self.head = temp
        node = self.head
        print(chr(0x2510)+(chr(0x0000)*(len(item)))+chr(0x250c))
        while node!=None:
            stackeditem = chr(0x2502)+node.data+chr(0x2502)
            print(stackeditem)
            node = node.next   
        print(chr(0x2514)+(chr(0x2500)*(len(item)-1))+chr(0x2518))
```

[image: here's the output]

Everytime I print, the lines just seems off. I tried to experiment using len() just to make it accurate, but everytime the item adds more characters it gets off again. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: From your picture it seems that whatever GUI you have uses a [proportional font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_font#Proportion). You will have a hard time adjusting the width of a string by adding spaces. Use a monospaced font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a monospace font as @Kable answered.

In addition to that, the last `print` print 1 less `chr(0x2500)`.

Some other notes:

- Use `\u2502` instead of `chr(0x2502)`.
- Separate dump functionality from `pushSLL`.
- The first and the last print only consider the length of the current node. It should calculate maximum length for all nodes.

---

```
class StackLL:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def pushSLL(self, item):
        temp = Node(str(item))
        temp.setNext(self.head)
        self.head = temp

    def dump(self):
        length = max(len(node.data) for node in self.allNodes()) if self.head else 0
        print('\u2510{}\u250c'.format(' '*length))
        for node in self.allNodes():
            print('\u2502{:<{}}\u2502'.format(node.data, length))
        print('\u2514{}\u2518'.format('\u2500'*length))

    def allNodes(self):
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            yield node
            node = node.next

s = StackLL()
s.pushSLL('Arc')
s.pushSLL('Circle')
s.pushSLL('Rect')
s.dump()
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 4):

Use a monospace font in IDLE settings and you are all good.